# Как отравить на почту сообщение о новом файле?

Tags: php, битрикс

Необходимо отправлять уведомления на почту всем пользователям которые имеют доступ к этому ресурсу. Т.е. есть общая папка и к ней имеют доступ 10 человек. Так все эти 10 человек должны получить уведомление на почту когда кто добавить новый файл.
Как понимаю реализуется это дело через события.

```
$eventManager = \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler('disk', 'onAfterAddFile', function (\Bitrix\Main\Event $event)
{
   #code tut
});
```

Права доступа можно получить вроде так:

```
CModule::IncludeModule('disk');
use Bitrix\Disk\BaseObject;

$object = BaseObject::loadById(ИД_объекта);
$rightsManager = Bitrix\Disk\Driver::getInstance()->getRightsManager();
$allListNormalizeRights = $rightsManager->getAllListNormalizeRights($object);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($allListNormalizeRights);
echo '</pre>';
```

Как мне это все связать? Сейчас только получается отправлять сообщение при каждом добавлении файла. Но мне нужно только тем кто имеет к каталогу доступ

Comment: находите сотрудников которым нужно отправить, вытаскиваете их почту и закидываете в массив. если функция отправки почты позволяет отправить нескольким получателям, то превращаете массив в строку с разделителем запятой. Если нет, то перебираете массив и отправляете каждому письмо.

Comment: Отправить нескольким получателям это не проблема. Основная проблема получить этот список пользователей которые имеют доступ к этому каталогу  в который добавляется файл

Comment: Думаю в сторону бизнес процессов. Создать отдельные группы/проекты  и настроить БП на добавление новых документов.
Подскажите, будет ли это правильно, какие могут возникнуть проблемы?

Comment: насколько я знаю в Битрикс24 есть бизнес-процессы для документов

Comment: Да все верно, так сделаю. Просто не хотелось плодить кучу групп.проектов. Но в это есть свои плюсы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Битрикс24 есть возможность создать бизнес-процесс для документов. Лучше всего это сработает если в Б24 есть группы, а у группы соответственно подключен модуль "Диск". Переходите в нужную группу, затем на вкладку "Диск". Затем нажимаем кнопку шестеренки.
[image: Открываем настройки]

В выпадающем меню выбираем пункт "Настройка бизнес-процессов" и в модальном окне ставим галочку "Активировать бизнес-процессы" и нажимаем сохранить.

Снова нажимаем ту самую шестеренку и теперь выбираем появившийся пункт "Бизнес-процессы".

Откроется страница со списком бизнес-процессов и их шаблонов для документов этой папки на диске.

Нажимаем "Создать последовательный бизнес-процесс".

Указываем название и проверяем чтобы была установлена галочка автоматически запускать при создании.

Нажимаем "Сохранить".

Из правого блока действий перетаскиваем блочок "Почтовое сообщение". Нажимаем на шестеренку и настраимваем.

Важное замечание! Вложения для почтовых уведомлений не поддерживаются. Ссылку на документ нужно указывать в теле письма.

Доступ будет ограничен доступ к группе, так что никто лишний уведомления не получит.

Такой способ выполняем для каждой группы в которую нужны уведомления. Но руками все делать не придется. Сделав один раз выполните экспорт бизнес-процесса, а в остальные группы просто его импортируйте.

Теперь члены группы будут получить уведомления на почты при добавлении документа в папку диска.

Чуть подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=57&LESSON_ID=2362).

Comment: Спасибо за подробную информацию! Особенно когда у битрикса документация отстает от версии продукта на несколько лет